# Code works in codepen and jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code for the header to show only when scrolling up only works in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MONSTER_COOKIE/w8hvcqfo/1/) or [codepen](http://codepen.io/CookieMonsta/pen/LxrJme). I wrote the code in my program, and it didn't work when I opened the file. I pasted all the code into codepen and jsfiddle, and it worked. What am I missing, or where did I go wrong?

HTML

```
       <body>
        <header class="nav-down">
            <h1>William Chen</h1>

        </header>
        <section class="module parallax parallax-1">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hi.</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="about">Lorem Ipsum Dolor hello</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module parallax parallax-2">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>What I can do.</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="about">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
    <h2 class="about">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module parallax parallax-3">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>I can help.</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="about">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <div class="contact">
            <a  class="contact" href="mailto:williamjchenca@gmail.com?Subject=Website%20Visitor" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o icon">`</i>Message Me</a>
        </div>


  </div>
</section>


        <script src="Scripts/menu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand');


header {
    background: #f5b335;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-up {
    top: -80px;
}

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
video.home {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

div.vid {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}
footer {
    background: #222020;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    width: 99%;
}

p.copyright{
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family:  'Roboto', sans-serif;

}

div.footer{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2em;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    color: #666666;
}



p {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

a.contact {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #36a2dc;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

i.icon {
    padding: 8px;
}

=========================================================== */
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* ============================================================
  SECTIONS
============================================================ */
section.module:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module h2 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
section.module p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
section.module p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module.content {
  padding: 40px 0;
}
section.module.parallax {
  height: 600px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
section.module.parallax h1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 600px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image: url("Images/Image1.jpg");
}
section.module.parallax-2 {
  background-image: url("Images/Image2.jpg");
}
section.module.parallax-3 {
  background-image: url("Images/Image3.jpeg");
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  section.module h2 {
    font-size: 42px;
  }
  section.module p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  section.module.parallax h1 {
    font-size: 96px;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
  section.module.parallax h1 {
    font-size: 160px;
  }
}
```

JS

```
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

P.S I've copied and pasted all my code in my own documents, into codepen and js fiddle numerous times, to make sure they're correct.(That's the same code in my html, css, js documents. Minus the head.)

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors and when you say *"it didn't work when I opened the file"* do you mean run it locally?

Comment: CHecked console. 3 errors:http://prntscr.com/e506uy. How do I fix them?

Comment: I think I can see the problem If you're trying to run this locally. Try adding `https:` to the javascript libraries url. Example `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js` also you should be using `$(document).ready(function() {});` https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Nope, doesn't work

Comment: This? http://pastebin.com/CCTxBBNJ Should be working just fine, I see no errors in my browser console after implementing my suggestions.

Comment: No, and the console still has this error:prntscr.com/e508g3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134934/discussion-between-newtojs-and-cookie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your menu.js file after you call the jquery js script.
Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/menu.js"></script>
```

Your jQuery needs to define itself before your menu.js can make any sense of the jQuery Library

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be adding your `$(window).scroll` listener before jQuery is initialized. You are also trying to set navbarHeight to a value based on a jQuery before jQuery has initialized. Try wrapping anything that relies on jQuery in a jQuery onReady listener:

```
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll, navbarHeight;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;

$().ready(function(){
  navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

  $(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
  });
})

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

This will ensure that the scroll listener is added *after* jQuery has initialized.

Comment: Just added that. Doesn't work. But the console has this error:http://prntscr.com/e508g3

Comment: It looks like line 5 also relies on jQuery being initialized. I update the answer above to account for that.